# Review link problem in review form on product page

Tags: magento-1.8, review

I couldn't understand why short review is linkable and which page  should it be redirect to
[image]

it show 404 error 
here's my review file it doesn't work for me..

**public_html/app/design/frontend/default/sns_nova/template/review/view.phtml**

```
<?php if($this->getProductData()->getId()): ?>
<div class="product-review">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Review Details') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="product-img-box">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductData()->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductData()->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProductData(), 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" height="125" width="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductData()->getName()) ?>" /></a>
        <?php if( $this->getRating() && $this->getRating()->getSize()): ?>
             <p class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Average Customer Rating') ?>:</p>
             <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProductData()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
        <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductData()->getName()) ?></h2>
        <?php if( $this->getRating() && $this->getRating()->getSize()): ?>
            <h3><?php echo $this->__('Product Rating:') ?></h3>
            <table class="ratings-table">
            <?php foreach ($this->getRating() as $_rating): ?>
                <?php if($_rating->getPercent()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode())) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo ceil($_rating->getPercent()) ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <?php echo $this->__('Product Review (submitted on %s):', $this->dateFormat($this->getReviewData()->getCreatedAt())) ?>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($this->getReviewData()->getDetail())) ?>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->getBackUrl() ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back to Product Reviews') ?></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: try reindex and check once......

Comment: @BabyinMagento  i tried but couldn't get solution.

Comment: did you checked with other products reviews section also, please check this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/tribal-striped-pattern-purple-apple-iphone-5-phone-case.html) , if you see under reviews you can see text `okay man` please click on that than you can see the page, it should be like that according to magento but its giving `404` for you....

Comment: this file is responsible for me `frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/view.phtml` , check with that file

Comment: @BabyinMagento I updated my question   I checked other products .

Comment: sorry i have no idea about whats wrong in code, but can you try replacing ordiginal file of `app/design/frontend/default/sns_nova/template/review/view.phtml` also replace original fresh magento file.....

Comment: Your question seems pretty incomplete to me. First of all, I don't see a link with a review title text. Second of all, does the link redirect you to page that is the red text in your screenshot? If so, that's just the product page (without the nice URL). This should always work, except for when the product ID doesn't exist.

So please add some additional information, so we can help you out.